# Ant script to replace "LEN(*)" to "length(*)" in a file

Tags: regex, ant

I have a requirement to replace every occurrence of LEN(*) to length(*) using ant script in a file. Below is the code I am using.

```
<replaceregexp file="G:/config.txt" match="LEN(\\*)" replace="length(*)" flags="g,i"/>
```

It is replacing to `length(*)(*)`. Looks like it is only considering `LEN`. Can anyone provide me the solution?

Comment: Try `LEN\\(\\*\\)`

Comment: Worked. Thanks.